# Mapping .svg (grease pencil) of face onto 3d model

Tags: modifiers, grease-pencil, 2d, vector, vector-mapping

**Essentially I want to project a drawing with grease pencil on a 3d surface so that the graphic grease pencil objects map physically onto the surface. project/map vector drawing (drawing) onto a 3d surface so that I have a useable, 3-Dimensional, grease pencil object projected onto a mesh**.

So far I have

- isolated a face [image: Separated vector graphic]
- a model that roughly is the shape of the face and alligned it to the graphic (AI made) [image: 3d model of the face]

My original idea was to align both and simply use some sort of modifier to do the job since i do not want to paint manually onto the surface. I have tried the shrinkwrap modifier but it snaps to the 3d model in a weird way [image: weird shrink wrap action]

*Project from view didnt work, maybe I am doing something wrong?*

**Is there a clever way to do this?**

Comment: The grease pencil strokes should move physically onto their point on the surface and not be projected as a texture (does it make a difference?)

Comment: is this your desired goal? To have a useable, 3-Dimensional, grease pencil object projected onto a mesh? If so, I think you should include this condition in your question.

Comment: ok, I changed it accordingly. Thank you for pointing this out:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have imported a svg file as a *Grease Pencil* object and have it aligned to a mesh, then you can use `Reproject Strokes` to achieve your projection.

Within *Edit* mode of your *Grease Pencil* object, select all elements you want projected, and go to
`Grease Pencil` $\rightarrow$ `Clean Up` $\rightarrow$ `Reproject Strokes` $\rightarrow$ and select `Surface`.

[image]

Your desired result should be acheived.

[image]

## Beware

Some things to consider when using `Reproject Strokes` to `Surface` are the direction of the projection, the misaligned vertices, and the use of multiple *Surfaces*.

`Reproject Strokes` only reprojects in the direction of your point of view. So, what happens when you're not in camera view? Reproject Strokes will default to your viewport view. Thus, make sure you are viewing your grease pencil object in the correct direction that you want to be projected before applying Reproject Strokes.

As a note, if you are using a camera to control the direction of projection, you can switch your camera from Perspective to Orthogonal to have your grease pencil projected 1:1 on your mesh.

[image]

If for some reason your grease pencil object has parts (*vertices*) that do not align with your mesh, then `Reproject Strokes` will not project those specific parts of your grease pencil.

[image]

To fix this, you can make sure your grease pencil overlaps with your mesh completely or increase the size of your mesh to cover your whole grease pencil object.

Lastly, `Reproject Strokes` to `Surface` will project to all surfaces/meshes in your space.

[image]

Although this may seem like a given but, if you want to avoid any unintentional conflicts with which surface to project, it would be best to hide any mesh that might interfere with your projection.

Answer (score 0):

Unwrap the face model as *Project from View* and then apply the drawing as an image texture onto the model

Comment: So am I right that you mean that I should not use my svg and instead use a jpg for this?

Comment: That depends if you want physical geometry or not.  If you don’t need physical geometry, then yes you are probably best using an image file